# Tip calculator keeps returning NaN. How to fix errors with Nan?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a tip calculator, and when I put in all the information it doesn't return the desired amount. Instead it returns Nan. Why does it do this, and what can be done to fix this?

I have tried manipulating the JS code and HTML but I can't seem to figure out what the deal is

```js
var billAmnt = document.getElementById('billAmnt').value;
var serviceQual = document.getElementById('serviceQual').value;
var peopleAmt = document.getElementById('peopleAmt').value;
var total = billAmnt * serviceQual / peopleAmt;

function calculateTip(){
    if(billAmnt === "" || serviceQual === 0){
        alert("Please enter values");
    }
    if(peopleAmt === "" || peopleAmt <= 1){
        peopleAmt = 1;
    }

    document.getElementById('totalTip').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = total;
    
    console.log(total);
}


calcButton.addEventListener('click', calculateTip);
```

````html
```
<section id="Calc">
    <jumbotron id="jumbotron">
            <div id="CalcContainer" class="container">
                    <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
                    <form action="">
                        <p class="lead mb-40">How much was your bill?</p>
                        <input type="text" id="billAmnt" placeholder="Bill Amount">
                
                        <p class="lead">How was your service?</p>
                        <select id="serviceQual" name="serviceQual">
                            <option disabled selected value="0">-- Choose an Option --</option>
                            <option value="0.3">30% - Outstanding</option>
                            <option value="0.2">20% - It was good</option>
                            <option value="0.15">15% - It was good, but not good enough</option>
                            <option value="0.10">10% - It was not good</option>
                            <option value="0.05">5% - It was terrible, but I'm nice enough to leave a tip</option>
                          </select>
            
                          <p id="numOfPeople"class="lead">How many people are sharing the bill?</p>
                          <input id="peopleAmt" type="text" placeholder="Number of People" > people
                          <div  class="button">
                                <button id="calcButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger ">Calculate!</button>
                          </div>
            
                          <div id="totalTip">
                            <sup>$</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
                            <small id="each">each</small>
                          </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
    </jumbotron>
   
</section>
````

Comment: "NaN" means not a number. Somewhere in you code, you probably switched the type of the value.

Comment: @Faizanpakiman698Khan Your variables are being set as soon as the script file loads, so the inputs have nothing in them at that time, so you are trying to do math on empty strings or nulls, you need to set those values inside of `calculateTip()` after your validation checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var`s you're setting are being set on page load - the values in these fields you're referencing will be blank. Thus, when attempting to apply arithmetic operations on blank values, you'll return a result that's `NaN`.

Move these `var` declarations to be set at runtime within your `calculateTip()` method, so the values will be pulled when the primary functionality is invoked:

```js
function calculateTip() {
  var billAmnt = document.getElementById('billAmnt').value;
  var serviceQual = document.getElementById('serviceQual').value;
  var peopleAmt = document.getElementById('peopleAmt').value;
  var total = billAmnt * serviceQual / peopleAmt;

  if (billAmnt === "" || serviceQual === 0) {
    alert("Please enter values");
  }
  if (peopleAmt === "" || peopleAmt <= 1) {
    peopleAmt = 1;
  }

  document.getElementById('totalTip').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = total;

  console.log(total);
}


calcButton.addEventListener('click', calculateTip);
```

````html
```
<section id="Calc">
  <jumbotron id="jumbotron">
    <div id="CalcContainer" class="container">
      <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
      <form action="">
        <p class="lead mb-40">How much was your bill?</p>
        <input type="text" id="billAmnt" placeholder="Bill Amount">

        <p class="lead">How was your service?</p>
        <select id="serviceQual" name="serviceQual">
          <option disabled selected value="0">-- Choose an Option --</option>
          <option value="0.3">30% - Outstanding</option>
          <option value="0.2">20% - It was good</option>
          <option value="0.15">15% - It was good, but not good enough</option>
          <option value="0.10">10% - It was not good</option>
          <option value="0.05">5% - It was terrible, but I'm nice enough to leave a tip</option>
        </select>

        <p id="numOfPeople" class="lead">How many people are sharing the bill?</p>
        <input id="peopleAmt" type="text" placeholder="Number of People"> people
        <div class="button">
          <button id="calcButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger ">Calculate!</button>
        </div>

        <div id="totalTip">
          <sup>$</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
          <small id="each">each</small>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </jumbotron>

</section>
````

Answer (score -1):

Variables are initialized before the user can enter them, on the page load. Just place your variables (`billAmnt`, `serviceQual`, `peopleAmt`, `total`) inside your calculateTip function

```js
function calculateTip(){
    var billAmnt = document.getElementById('billAmnt').value;
    var serviceQual = document.getElementById('serviceQual').value;
    var peopleAmt = document.getElementById('peopleAmt').value;
    var total = billAmnt * serviceQual / peopleAmt;


    if(billAmnt === "" || serviceQual === 0){
        alert("Please enter values");
    }
    if(peopleAmt === "" || peopleAmt <= 1){
        peopleAmt = 1;
    }

    document.getElementById('totalTip').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = total;
}


calcButton.addEventListener('click', calculateTip);
```

```html
<section id="Calc">
    <jumbotron id="jumbotron">
            <div id="CalcContainer" class="container">
                    <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
                    <form action="">
                        <p class="lead mb-40">How much was your bill?</p>
                        <input type="text" id="billAmnt" placeholder="Bill Amount">

                        <p class="lead">How was your service?</p>
                        <select id="serviceQual" name="serviceQual">
                            <option disabled selected value="0">-- Choose an Option --</option>
                            <option value="0.3">30% - Outstanding</option>
                            <option value="0.2">20% - It was good</option>
                            <option value="0.15">15% - It was good, but not good enough</option>
                            <option value="0.10">10% - It was not good</option>
                            <option value="0.05">5% - It was terrible, but I'm nice enough to leave a tip</option>
                          </select>

                          <p id="numOfPeople"class="lead">How many people are sharing the bill?</p>
                          <input id="peopleAmt" type="text" placeholder="Number of People" > people
                          <div  class="button">
                                <button id="calcButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger ">Calculate!</button>
                          </div>

                          <div id="totalTip">
                            <sup>$</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
                            <small id="each">each</small>
                          </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
    </jumbotron>

</section>
```